# Is there a way to analyze assemblies in a legacy application and see how portable my code is in the newest .Net version such as .net8.0 or .net9.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, upgrade, analyzer

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently working on a legacy .NET application, and I'm looking for guidance on assessing the portability of my code to the latest .NET versions, specifically .NET 8.0 and .NET 9.0. I want to ensure that my application can smoothly transition to the newer frameworks while maintaining compatibility.

I have looked into the .Net Portability Analyzer, but I am unable to generate a report on the newest .net targets such as 8.0 or 9.0.

Any insights, tips, or experiences you can share regarding analyzing legacy applications for portability to the latest .NET versions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Define "legacy" here for me.  Is it legacy because of the .NET version? Or is the application behavior legacy because it needs some new features that would be best created in the latest .NET 8+? I'm asking because .NET Framework 4.8 isn't going away, and will remain in support for a long time. If you just need to 'upgrade', it's not worth it.  If you need new features, can you make the new features in a separate application that would be .NET 8+? The latter is what the .NET [Upgrade Assistant](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant) tool can help you with.

Comment: I work for a company that specializes in modernizing old outdated applications. We are looking into modernizing old versions of .NET such 3.0 or 4.0 into 8.0. We wanted to see if there is any tool out there that can analyze such comparisons and generate a detailed report.

Comment: if the application is c#, and it is NOT a Web Forms project, then the migration tool will help, and changes in code will be very small. If this is a webforms application, then you have to re-write it into a MVC application.  So, conversions of a MVC application, and a c# one? Then such a migration is quite simple, since most .net code as framework will run with few if any changes as .net core. However, as noted, the 2 exceptions here are if this is vb.net, and if this is a web forms project. There is no automated tools to convert to MVC, and the stumbling block is WebForms to MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no such tool that will generate a detailed report that can be used to glean an upgrade path.

The .NET Portability Analyzer is not the tool you are looking for. It can't be used on VS 2022, and .NET 6+ only runs on VS 2022.

The successor to the now deprecated .NET Portability Analyzer, which is the NET Upgrade Assistant binary analysis (preview) still does not generate a report of necessary code changes required to update .NET versions.

REF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer

> API Port has been deprecated in favor of binary analysis by the .NET Upgrade Assistant. The backend service of API Port has been shut down, so to use the tool, you must use it offline. For more information, see .NET API Port README.

REF: https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant/blob/main/docs/binary_analysis.md

> The Binary Analysis feature (analyzebinaries) of Upgrade Assistant allows you to determine if a binary - for which you may/may not have the source code - is able to be upgraded to a target framework and platform combination of your choosing.

The following recommendations are based on my experience with ASP.NET.  I am not familiar at all with upgrading desktop or mobile applications.

In my opinion, the two best routes are:

1. Use the .NET Upgrade assistant as it is intended with the side-by-side option (YARP)
2. Update .NET Framework apps to the latest .NET Framework version, and utilize the upgrade paths.

REF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

What has worked for me in the past:

- Migrate .NET Framework 3/4.X to .NET Framework 4.8
- Then, .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET Core 3.1
- Then, .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6

Migrations from .NET 5+ onwards are in my opinion fairly nominal unless you need to take advantage of newer language features.